# Did Moses have more than one wife in his lifetime?

Tags: old-testament, moses

EX 3:1 Jethro was the father-in-law of Moses.

NU 10:29, JG 4:11 (KJV) Hobab was the father-in-law of Moses.

This seems to suggest that he did. Curious if anyone else has looked into this.

Answer (score 4):

About Jethro, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jethro_(biblical_figure)) states:

> There is some disagreement over the name(s) of Moses' father-in-law. In the KJV translation of Judges 4:11, a man named Hobab appears as Moses' father-in-law, while Numbers 10:29 makes him "the son of Raguel [Reuel] the Midianite, Moses' father in law". Reuel is noted Exodus 2:16, as "a priest of Midian" who had seven daughters. Exodus 2:18 "the girls returned to Reuel their father". Reuel becomes Moses' father in law in Exodus 2:21 "Moses agreed to stay with the man, who gave his daughter Zipporah to Moses in marriage."
>
> In Numbers 10:29, the Hebrew for the name Raguel is the same as the Hebrew for Reuel. The reason for the difference is that the Hebrew character ע (ayin) in רעואל is sometimes used merely as a vowel and sometimes as "g", "ng", and "gn", because of the difficulty of its pronunciation by European speakers. Re-u-el, with the first syllable strong accented, is nearer to the true pronunciation. Some suppose he was father to Hobab, who was also called Jethro, a likely possibility.[10]
>
> Another thing to consider is that there is only one Biblical Hebrew word for both "brother-in-law" and "father-in-law" (chathan).[11] It is, in fact, the word for any and all relations by marriage. If one takes into account the Biblical custom of multiple names for one person as well as Numbers 10:29 calling Hobab Reuel's son, Reuel and Jethro both appear as Moses' father-in-law,[12] while Hobab may be seen as his brother-in-law. However, this is disputed among theologians.[13][14]

An example of a theological position about the issue can be found in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43711387). The author argues that the contradiction is apparent. He states (p.9):

> The   information  which  has  been  preserved  in  the   traditions   dealing   with  Hobab  can  be  best  understood  to   say  that   Hobab,   son-in-law   of   Moses,  was  a  Midianite  belonging  to  the  clan  of  Reuel  and  a  smith  by  profession.    Jethro,  priest  of  Midian  and  father-in-law  of  Moses,  was  a  member  of  the  same  clan  (Reuel).   Although  their  roles  have  been  somewhat  confused  in  later  reflections  of  the  early  Israelite  traditions,  there  is  still  enough  information  preserved  to  suggest  this  reasonable  solution  to  the  puzzle.

Details are in the paper, but for example he suggests that their profession (as stated in the Bible) were too different for them being the same person. I quote (pp.6-7):

> the  roles  of  Jethro  and   Hobab  are  entirely   different.   Jethro  appears  as  an  old  man  with  seven  daughters  (Ex 2,16),  who  advises  his  son-in-law  from  the  wealth  of  his  own  experience  (Ex  18).   Hobab,  on  the  other   hand,   appears  as a vigorous  younger  man  whom
>     Moses  wishes  to  act as  guide  in  the  wilderness  (Nm  10,29-32) ...
>
> We  have  only  to  change  the  vocalization  from *hôtën* to *hätän*   where   Hobab is mentioned,  and our  difficulties  vanish:  render  Nm 10,29, "Hobab, son  of  Reuel,  the  Midianite,  son-in-law  of  Moses."   The  fact  that  both  Hobab  and  Jethro  belonged  to  the  clan  of  Reuel  should  cause  no  difficulty  whatsoever,  since  the  West-Semitic  nomads  were  as  a  rule  endogamous,   so one would expect  Moses' son-in-law  and father-in-law  both to come  from the  same clan.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer deals ably with the matter of the name of Jethro.

But the main question (Did Moses have more than one wife in his lifetime ?) opens up another factor.

It is my understanding that Moses married again after the incident concerning the circumcising of the child born to Jethro's daughter, Zipporah, who was displeased regarding circumcision. Exodus 4:24-26.

> Then Zipporah took a sharp stone, and cut off the foreskin of her son, and cast it at his feet, and said, Surely a bloody husband art thou to me. [Exodus 4:25 KJV]

Moses sent Zipporah away as is recorded in Exodus 18:2 when Jethro brings her back again. My own assumption is that Moses responded to Zipporah's displeasure and sent her back to her father. But Jethro was able to encourage her to accept her situation and he brought her back to Moses in the wilderness.

> Then Jethro, Moses' father in law, took Zipporah, Moses' wife, after he had sent her back [...] And Jethro, Moses' father in law, came with his sons and his wife unto Moses into the wilderness, where he encamped at the mount of God : [Exodus 18 : 2 and 5]

In Numbers 12:1 we read that Miriam and Aaron spoke against Moses because he had married an Ethiopan woman.

> And Miriam and Aaron spake against Moses because of the Ethiopian woman whom he had married: for he had married an Ethiopian woman.[KJV]

My own assumption is that Moses married a second time, perhaps while Zipporah was in departure from him.

Comment: According to Josephus, the "Ethiopian woman" came before this incident.  She was a princess that Moses had a political marriage to as part of his time as a prince of Egypt.

Comment: Both suggestions are astounding. Much of this is not taught in sunday school :)

Comment: @MasonWheeler I do not see why Aaron and Moses could possibly object to a 'political' marriage whilst Moses was yet in Egypt (at least forty years prior to his return to Hebrew society) being brought up in the household of Pharaoh. I regard Josephus' explanation as very far fetched and I cannot accept it, personally.